# Redux load state async and using with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am new to React and Redux and currently I am working on React project and have some questions about Redux integration.

## 1. Load state asynchronously

I have `index.js` file which is entry point of my project:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Here I import `store.js`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

export default store
```

And `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import UserRoute from './components/UserRoute'
import GuestRoute from './components/GuestRoute'
import Menu from './components/Menu'
import LoginPage from './components/pages/LoginPage'
import SignupPage from './components/pages/SignupPage'
import HomePage from './components/pages/HomePage'
import ProfilePage from './components/pages/ProfilePage'
import GroupsPage from './components/pages/GroupsPage'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <GuestRoute exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <GuestRoute exact path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />
        <UserRoute exact path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
        <UserRoute exact path="/groups" component={GroupsPage} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

I cut some code to make it more readable for you. Notice `UserRoute` and `GuestRoute` components. `UserRoute` allows only authenticated users to navigate to the page and `GuestRoute` does the opposite. I have user token saved in `localStorage`, then I use it to get user data from server. I want to get response before rendering my `App` component. If I don't wait response and my location is `/profile` for example, then `UserRoute` will redirect me to main page. To avoid redirect I can do this:

```
getState().then(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
})
```

But is it good way to load state before rendering? Or there are other "better" ways to do this?

## 2. Importing store in other files

How can I get current state in axios request? Is it OK to export store in `store.js` and then import it in `api.js` file:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store'

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001',
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
})

// Used to set current JWT token(part of third question)
export function setAuthorizationHeader(token = '') {
  if (token) {
    client.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
  } else {
    delete client.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
  }
}

export default {
  user: {
    fetch() {
      return client.get('/user').then(res => res.data)
    },
    // other api calls which use current state of store
  }
}
```

## 3. Not pure action creators

This question is about action creators. I have following action creators:

```
import api, { setAuthorizationHeader } from '../api'

export function setUser(user) {
  return { type: 'SET_USER', user }
}
export function setUserToken(token) {
  return { type: 'SET_USER_TOKEN', token }
}
export const login = credentials => async dispatch => {
  const { user, token } = await api.user.login(credentials)
  // TODO: refactor this
  setAuthorizationHeader(token)

  dispatch(setUserToken(token))
  dispatch(setUser(user))
}
```

When I get response from server I set `Authorization` header for axios client. Is it OK that they are not pure functions?

Also you can look at my [repository](https://github.com/olegmisar/school-journal) to get more understanding how code works.

Comment: I would suggest that you break up your question into multiple questions, or do a summary at the bottom :)

Comment: "Is it OK that they are not pure functions?" Yes I would say so. Sometimes there need to be side effects. Don't forget to unset the auth header when the user logs out though.